# How can I tell sqlmap to check another link?

Tags: php, http-post, sql-injection, session-state, sqlmap

I have a sql injection point using `POST` request at the url `http://example.com/submit.php` which works with the data `id=3&submit=submit`.

This saves the `ID` in a session `$_SESSION[ id ]` and you see the output result (which is the name and surname of the user with `id=3`) in another url `example.com/theother.php`.

Now how can I tell `Sqlmap` to inject in the first url but to check the other url (and not the first url) for any sql "modifications"?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you are talking about [second-order attack](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage#second-order-attack).

The following command *might* do what you want:

```
python sqlmap.py -u "http://example.com/submit.php" --data "id=3&submit=submit" -p id --second-order "http://example.com/theother.php"
```